# Populating divs with data from JSON reply using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

In `PHP` we can go through an array of objects or data and generate HTML as we do it. For example:

```
<?php foreach ($array as $entity)?>
<div class = "feeds">
   <h1><?php $entity['title']?></h1>
   <p><?php $entity['overview']?></p>
   <a href=""<?php $entity['link']?>"">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Now,i have a page where i would be calling a .php file using jquery, which will return a big JSON reply. The JSON reply is like this:

```
[
  {
    "created_at": "Sat Nov 07 16:50:09 +0000 2015",
    "user_name": "Entertainment Weekly",
    "text": "Stephen Colbert conjures up fake #HarryPotter spoilers on   #TheLateShow: https://t.co/vA9IA3NXUA https://t.co/PIcyseXXNq",

  },
  {
    "created_at": ".......",
    "user_name": ".........",
    "text": "..............",

  },
  ...
]
```

now i want to translate this reply into divs of html content using jquery. Any assistance on that is much appreciated.

Comment: send `json_encode`d response to the ajax and do jquery loop `for(i=0;i<count;i++)`

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<=array.length; i++) {
     var html = '<h1>' + array[i].title + '</h1><p>' + array[i].overview + '</p><a href=""' + array[i].link + '"">Read More</a>';

     $('.feeds').append(html);
}
```

Comment: assuming that i am getting an array of json objects, how do i do this?

Comment: As I did, I supposed `array` is an array of objects, but if you edit your question with your JSON I could be more specific in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First off, I would use Angular or some other platform instead.  That said, in jQuery, I'd start with a target div in the document, like so:

```
<div id="feedsList"></div>
```

Then you need to get your data in json format.  The weird-looking commands that start with a "." are just adding onto the previous element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var data = [
        {
            title: "title 1",
            overview: "overview 1",
            link: "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
        },
        {
            title: "title 2",
            overview: "overview 2",
            link: "http://www.disney.com"
        },
        {
            title: "title 3",
            overview: "overview 3",
            link: "http://www.angular.com"
        }
    ];

    var wrapper_class = "feeds",
        title_class = "feed_title",
        overview_class = "feed_overview",
        link_class = "read_more",
        feedsList = $('#feedsList');


    data.forEach(function(feeds) {
        $("<div>")
            .addClass(wrapper_class)
            .append(
                $("<h3>")
                    .addClass(title_class)
                    .html(feeds.title)
            )
            .append(
                $("<p>")
                    .addClass(overview_class)
                    .html(feeds.overview)
            )
            .append(
                $("<a>")
                    .attr("target","_blank")
                    .attr("href",feeds.link)
                    .addClass(link_class)
                    .html("read more...")
            )
            .appendTo(feedsList);
    });
});
```

Here's a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mckinleymedia/mdd09vf9/

<strike>Oh, I changed your h1s to h3s because you should only have one h1 on the page.</strike>

Hope this helps.

Comment: "you should only have one h1 on the page" No, you really really shouldn't. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#rank for a trivial counter-example.

Comment: Interesting.  I haven't kept up with this header recommendation for html5.  I'll cross that off pending further research.  Thanks for the heads up, Felix.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  "h1": "qwe",
  "para": "12312312312312312312321",
  "anchor": "google.com"
}]
console.log(data)
$.each(data, function(index,value) {
$('h1').text(value.h1);
$('p').text(value.para);
$('a').text(value.anchor);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="feeds">
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <a href="">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Try something like this

Comment: but in this solution, where are the divs being appeneded after one another? given the the var data has 3 objects, 3 divs are needed to be generated,right?